# Pyperclip module not working

Tags: python, pyperclip

I would like to use pyperclip to copy to clipboard and paste from it, but it seems that it is not working.

When I try to use `pyperclip.copy("some string")`, I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\pyperclip\__init__.py", line 68, in winSetClipboard
    ctypes.cdll.msvcrt.strcpy(ctypes.c_char_p(pchData), bytes(text))
TypeError: string argument without an encoding

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    pyperclip.copy("hello")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\pyperclip\__init__.py", line 71, in winSetClipboard
    ctypes.cdll.msvcrt.strcpy(ctypes.c_char_p(pchData), bytes(text, 'ascii'))
OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000000000000
```

On the other hand, when I use pyperclip.paste() even if I had copied something previously, I get nothing printed, and even sometimes python crashes.

I am using windows 10 and python 3.5. I have also tried with python 3.4.3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The pyperclip docs say it only handles "plain text". Maybe it doesn't like Unicode. What happens if you try `pyperclip.copy(b"some string")`?

Comment: When I run `pyperclip.copy(b"some string")` I get just the second error that I have mentioned.

Comment: It may be worthwhile to report your problem on the [pyperclip issues page](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip/issues).

Comment: Thank u I will do it right away.

Comment: I noticed it was updated on PyPI just yesterday (9/23). You may want to try updating to the latest version and see if your problem is already resolved.

Comment: I am already using the last version 1.5.13